# UISplitViewController display the popover from right instead of left

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios4, uisplitviewcontroller

So I've implemented an iPad application it has a UISplitView implemented. i'm using the slide gesture to show the popover controller instead of a bar button. the problem is that by default the popover slides in from left I want the slider to move in from the right. I've tried finding a solution to this but couldn't find anything yet so I thought i better ask this myself and see if its even possible.

I know this exists: http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad/
but im not too keen on using a 3rd party library.

If you know any possible solution or a work around please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess theres no other way but to use a custom made uisplitview... In the end i had to re-design my whole app and this time I had to create a custom UISplitViewController from a scratch.

Apple should be a little more flexible with their publically

Comment: Using the `MGSplitViewController` is actually pretty risk-free. Very stable and easy to use.